# How to find intersection point of a line in a plane in 3D space using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, line, cartesian-coordinates

I have a plain with known four co-ordinates and a line with two known co-ordinates as shown in figure.
[image]

The four co-ordinates of plane are

```
 A = (-5    -5    -8)
 B = ( 15    15    -8)
 C = ( 15    15    12)
 D = ( -5    -5    12)
```

The co-ordinates of line are

```
M = (1.3978,40,6.1149)
N = 4.3943, 4.8078,0.3551)
```

In this case line and plain intersects,then how can I find point of intersection of line and plane in 3D space by using MATLAB?
or How can I check both are intersecting or not?

I have tried to find solution by following  video [tutorial to find equation of plane from three points](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qYJfKG-3l8) and [tutorial for finding point where line intersects a plain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVvvy5hsQwk)

But in my case, equation of plane is zero. So I am confused. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Manu

Answer (score 2):

I would use simple linear algebra to find the intersection point.

Let `n` be normal to the plain (you can calculate it as a vector product of  say `N = cross(AB, AD)`, then unit `n = N / |N|` where `|N| = sqrt(dot(N, N))` is length of vector N.

You can use the following function from [matlabcentral](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17751-straight-line-and-plane-intersection?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) which covers all the corner cases as well (such as when the line is parallel to the plane) and describes them in the comments.

**Example from comment:**

```
A =[ -6.8756 39.9090 10.0000],B =[ -6.0096 40.4090 10.0000],C =[ -6.0096 40.4090 11.0000],D=[ -6.8756 39.9090 11.0000];
P0 =[ 1.3978 40.0000 6.1149],P1 =[ 4.3943 -4.8078 0.3551];
```

I don't know where you made a mistake, but I am pretty sure there is an intersection point which is outside your segment. So you should have got `check=3`. Here is the output of step by step operation:

```
>> AB = B-A
AB = 0.8660    0.5000         0
>> AD = D-A
AD = 0     0     1
>> n = cross(AB,AD)/sqrt(dot(cross(AB,AD),cross(AB,AD)))
n = 0.5000   -0.8660         0
>> [I,check]=plane_line_intersect(n,A,P0,P1)
I = 1.0961   44.5116    6.6948
check = 3
```

It produces the same results with any other point (B, C or D) passed in. `check=3` means there is an intersection point I, which is outside of the P01 segment.

As a verification step, notice that normal n has `Nz = 0` which means that it's perpendicular to the Z axis. The only way a line wouldn't intersect with it is if it would be parallel to Z axis (and therefore vector P01 would be parallel to Z and have zero Z component).

Your P01 is not aligned with Z:

```
>> P01 = P1 - P0
P01 = 2.9965  -44.8078   -5.7598
```

Comment: when I checked for plane points A =[ -6.8756   39.9090   10.0000],B =[ -6.0096   40.4090   10.0000],C =[  -6.0096   40.4090   11.0000],D=[  -6.8756   39.9090   11.0000] and line points P0 =[ 1.3978   40.0000    6.1149],P1 =[ 4.3943   -4.8078    0.3551], it results when using your function, check=1 and I=[-21.2205   31.6268   -6.3689]. Actually there is no intersecting. Can you please explain, why it result like this?

Comment: You only need 3 points to define the plane, 4 points could be not co-planar. Yours are, so this isn't a problem. However, I am failing to reproduce your output and result I'm getting looks reasonable to me. Please take a look at the output I'm getting with your inputs. Hopefully you'll spot a mistake.

Comment: This doesn't change what I wrote above with regards to your example, but I corrected the normal calculation - the one I had initially wasn't unit vector in case of non-orthogonal AB and AD. In your example they were, so don't know if that somehow happened to be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, there is a change in line points,  P0 =[6.3300   -1.8031    2.5170] and P1 =[15.0000   91.9500  -22.4032]. Plane points are the same as above. In this case also check=1 but expected is 3. Can you please check? I need to find intersecting point of line inside the rectangular plane with above corner co-ordinates. Sometimes, it may be the confusion

Comment: I followed following link, I think that now I find solution https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html Thanks a lot @isp-zax