# 3d line intersection with plane

Tags: math, line-intersection

I have two points in my world, P0 and P1 (xyz,..) which basically represent the start of my line and the end of my line. I also have a plane/side with 4 points, ABCD (xyz,..).

What I want to do is send a "ray" (in this case a line) through the plane and check whether or not it intersects with it. I have used this ([How to find intersection point of a line in a plane in 3D space using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481111/how-to-find-intersection-point-of-a-line-in-a-plane-in-3d-space-using-matlab)) question as a reference and this function [mathlabcentral](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17751-straight-line-and-plane-intersection?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). I tried the example "isp-zax" gave and that does give me the same values as he does, but as soon as I plop in my own values it is clearly wrong. The answers formula;

```
>> AB = B-A
AB = 0.8660    0.5000         0
>> AD = D-A
AD = 0     0     1
>> n = cross(AB,AD)/sqrt(dot(cross(AB,AD),cross(AB,AD)))
n = 0.5000   -0.8660         0
>> [I,check]=plane_line_intersect(n,A,P0,P1)
I = 1.0961   44.5116    6.6948
check = 3
```

--

So the first set of line points (P) work perfectly fine which it should (see image) but if I move the end point of the line (P1) outside of the plane it still says it intersects (see 2nd image). What could cause this?

```
A = [1312.901701, 2360.12542566832, 74.24415425756794];
B = [1312.901701, 2423.58274087539, 88.31230234462595];
C = [1312.901701, 2371.241313396465, 24.103624956470995];
D = [1312.901701, 2434.698628603535, 38.171773043529];

P0 = [1495.468628, 2261.038086, 161.329498];
P1 = [1153.250854, 2479.341797, -14.787056];
```

[image: Text]

--

[image: Text]

This is it in javascript;

```
const ab = subtract(B, A);
const ad = subtract(D, A);
const n = divide(cross(ab, ad), sqrt(dot(cross(ab, ad), cross(ab, ad))));

const intersects = planeLineIntersect(n, A, P0, P1);

function planeLineIntersect(n, v0, p0, p1) {
    const u = subtract(p1, p0);
    const w = subtract(p0, v0);
    
    const D = dot(n, u);
    const N = -dot(n, w);

    let check = 0;

    if (abs(D) < 0.0000001) {
        if (N === 0) {
            check = 2;

            return check;
        }

        check = 0;

        return check;
    }

    const sI = divide(N, D);
    const I = add(p0, multiply(sI, u)); // not used

    if (sI < 0 || sI > 1) {
        check = 3;
    } else check = 1;

    return check;
}
```

Comment: The intersection of a line to an infinite plane is a very easy problem. But your "plane" isn't a plane, its a closed polygon that lies on in infinite plane. So the problem is finding if the point defined from the first part is [inside a polygon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html).

Comment: Also, a quick "weeding" is to take the interesection point on the (infinitely long) line through p0 and p1, and then simply doing a distance check: if `dist(p0,p1)` is less than `dist(p0,intersection)` then even though the maths knows where the intersection "would" be, there isn't one.

Comment: A problem exists when points _ABCD_ do not all lie on the same plane.